# dll как массив байтов

Tags: c#, assembly

Можно ли сохранить `dll` как массив байтом а затем загрузить массив в память(не на диск а именно в память) программы через `Assembly.Load` что бы использовать методы из массива байтов как из обычной сборки?

Comment: dll и есть массив байтов. Можно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен в 100% правильности ответа, но думаю, что можно организовать хранение байт массива в `MemoryStream` и в момент когда сборка понадобится загрузить её оттуда.

Вот этот пример вполне работает:

```
byte[] asmBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Foo\\asm.dll");
var asm = Assembly.Load(asmBytes);
var types = asm.DefinedTypes;
```